# multi dimensional array with different elements; VBA excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Is it possible to create multi dimensional array with different element types (string and integer)?
I tried like this but wan't work

```
BT = Range("A12")
ReDim IT(BT) As String
ReDim RBT(BT) As Integer
ReDim IT_RBT(IT, RBT) as ???? how to create multi dim array with different variables type

Range("B2").Select
i = 0
Do
    i = i + 1
    IT(i) = ActiveCell
    RBT(i) = i
    IT_RBT(i, i) = ????  how to enter values in such array ????
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop While ActiveCell <> ""
```

Thank you

Comment: `Dim myArray As Variant`

Comment: Think you'll need `ubound` too. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Why do you need a third array?

Comment: I already tried "As Variant". In that case RBT is highlighted and "type mismatch" error appears. Third array should keep track about connection between elements from first two arrays.

Comment: We still don't know why you need 3 arrays, or what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Variant` array.

```
Dim values() As Variant
```

Now, your code is making assumptions that should be removed.

```
BT = Range("A12") '<~ implicit: ActiveSheet.Range("A12").Value
```

If you mean to pull the value of `A12` from a particular specific worksheet, then you should qualify that `Range` member call with a proper `Worksheet` object. See [CodeName: Sheet1](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/code-name-sheet1/) for more info, but long story short if that sheet is in `ThisWorkbook` you can do this:

```
BT = Sheet1.Range("A12").Value
```

And now assumptions are gone. Right? Wrong. `BT` isn't declared (at least not here). If it's declared and it's not a `Variant`, then there's a potential *type mismatch* error with that assignment. In fact, the only data type that can accept *any* cell value, is `Variant`:

```
Dim BT As Variant
BT = Sheet1.Range("A12").Value
```

Here, we're assuming `BT` is a numeric value:

```
ReDim IT(BT) As String
```

That's another assumption. We don't *know* that `BT` is numeric. We don't even know that it's a value that *can* be coerced into a numeric data type: we should bail out if that's not the case:

```
If Not IsNumeric(BT) Then
    MsgBox "Cell A12 contains a non-numeric value; please fix & try again."
    Exit Sub
End If

ReDim IT(BT) As String
```

Now that will work... but then, only the upper bound is explicit; is this a 0-based or a 1-based array? If the module says `Option Base 1`, then it's 1-based. Otherwise, it's 0-based - implicit array lower bounds are an easy source of "off-by-one" bugs (like how you're populating the arrays starting at index 1, leaving index 0 empty). Always make array bounds explicit:

```
ReDim IT(1 To BT) As String
```

Unclear why you need 3 arrays at all, and why you're only populating `(i,i)` in the 3rd one - you cannot populate a 2D array with a `Do...Loop` structure; you need every value of `y` for each value of `x`, and unless you hard-code the width of the array, that's a nested loop.

Moreover, looping on the `ActiveCell` and `Select`ing an `Offset` is making the code 1) very hard to follow, and 2) incredibly inefficient.

Consider:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Sheet1.Rows).End(xlUp).Row

ReDim values(1 To lastRow, 1 To 2) As Variant

Dim currentRow As Long
For currentRow = 2 To lastRow
    Dim currentColumn As Long
    For currentColumn = 1 To 2
        values(currentRow, currentColumn) = Sheet1.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).Value
    Next
Next
```

Now, if we don't need any kind of logic in that loop and all we want is to grab a 2D variant array that contains every cell in `B2:B???`, then we don't need any loops:

```
Dim values As Variant
values = Sheet1.Range("A2:B" & lastRow).Value
```

And done: `values` is a 1-based (because it came from a `Range`), 2D variant array that contains the values of every cell in `A2:B{lastRow}`.

Note, code that consumes this array will need to avoid assumptions about the data types in it.

Comment: Cell A12 has numeric value. First array is list of items. Second array should be position of item in the list. Third array should keep connection between item and position. Like: item1 position 5, item 3 position 4 and ....so on. Third array is actually one on one.

Comment: "Cell A12 has numeric value" - *You* know that; your code doesn't, and it *will* blow up when (not if - *especially* with an implicit reference to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is) it doesn't. Again, not clear why you'd need to have an array to hold the position of the items of another array - that's what the array index is! As for "connection between item and position", that's unclear as well. In any case the answer to your question is "use a `Variant` array".

Answer (score 1):

As @SJR has said, variant will allow for this. The below example is a easy example how to add different types to an array. Instead of x or y you can have a cell on a worksheet.

```
Dim array1() As Variant, i As Long
Dim x As String, y As Long

    x = "5"
    y = 1

    For i = 1 To 10

        ReDim Preserve array1(1 To 2, 1 To i)
        array1(1, i) = x
        array1(2, i) = y
        y = y + 1
        Debug.Print array1(1, i) & "," & array1(2, i) ' This is where you insert output

    Next
```

Comment: Note: `ReDim Preserve` inside a loop is very inefficient, since the entire array is being copied over, *at every single iteration*. Consider sizing the array *before* you start looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
BT = Range("A12")
ReDim IT(BT) As String
ReDim RBT(BT) As Integer

Dim IT_RBT(1 to 2) 'variant
IT_RBT(1) = IT   'add String array
IT_RBT(2) = RBT  'add Integer array
```

... this will keep your typed arrays functional but it's not a 2D array and you'd need to use notation like

```
IT_RBT(1)(1)  'String type
IT_RBT(2)(1)  'Integer type
```